# representation of fractional number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

You can write any fractional number, $x$, in base $10$ as $\frac{a_1}{2} + \frac{a_2}{2^2} + \frac{a_3}{2^3} + ....$  where the $a_i$ are either 0 or 1 (and then you can write $x = 0.a_1a_2a_3 ....$). Given the $a_i$ it can be straight forward to determine the number $x$, but if you are given $x$ how do you determine the $a_i$?

Comment: The representation you mention is the binary representation of a real number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987176/how-do-you-convert-a-fraction-to-binary

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually mean base 2 and that $0<x<1$ you define the following sequences $$x_0=x; \quad a_{n+1} = \lfloor 2x_n\rfloor; \quad x_{n+1} = \{2x_n\} \quad \text{for }n>0$$
Here $\{\dots\}$ and $\lfloor \dots \rfloor$ are the fractional and integer part functions.